# Accessing shared memory in a process after shmdt() and before shmctl(shmid, ipc_RMID, 0)

Tags: c, linux, process, shared-memory

Assuming I have a pointer `*p` to a shared memory previously allocated.

If one of the processes calls `shmdt()` to detach the shared memory segment, and then tries to assign a value e.g. :

```
*p = 0;
```

before calling `shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0)` for destruction.

Will doing so result in an error? I'm having trouble understanding which and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is an error, and will most likely result in a segfault.

When you call `shmget(2)` to allocate a shared memory segment, it is not immediately put anywhere in the virtual address space of your process. That is, there is no address you could write to that would write data into the segment.

The job of `shmat(2)` is to put (map) the segment into the address space of your process. (In System V shared memory parlance this is called *attaching* the segment, but that terminology isn't used much elsewhere. *Mapping* is more common.) After a successful call to `shmat()`, the segment will appear at some address, and that address is returned as the result of `shmat()`.

Calling `shmdt(2)` on a previously attached segment makes that segment once again disappear from the virtual address space of your process. Trying to write to an address that was previously part of the mapping is an error, since the mapping is no longer there. That does not mean the data that was written into the segment is lost however -- it's just not mapped anywhere. You could re-map (re-attach) the segment with another call to `shmat(2)` to access the data once again.

Only after you destroy the segment with `shmctl()` and `IPC_RMID` is the memory actually freed (once the segment is no longer attached anywhere).

To make things a bit more concrete, here's how a simple implementation of shared memory could work, at a high level:

- `shmget()` allocates as much physical memory as you request for the segment.
- `shmat()` programs the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) and sets things up in the kernel so that some address range in your process maps to the segment.
- `shmdt()` does the reverse operation and removes the mapping.
- `shmctl()` with `IPC_RMID` deallocates the physical memory of the segment (marks it as free).

As a side note, it is possible to use `shmat(2)` to map the same segment to multiple locations in the address space. This is possible since it's purely a virtual memory operation.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy response !